# ios core data how to implement the sql transaction function?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

like title. I use core data to insert item, i insert 100 items , it`s too slow. How to up the insert speed? Core Data whicher has transaction funcation?

Comment: Can you show us how you are creating your items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is to `save` in Core Data after all 100 objects have been inserted as opposed to after each insert.

When objects are inserted into Core Data they are only present in memory. To persist your new objects to disc you should save which will take all changes (inserts, updates and deletes) and write them to disc together.

---

If you look at [the documentation for -insertObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/insertObject%3a) (below) you can read that inserting an object only registers the object for being inserted when changes are saved.

> ## insertObject:
>
> Registers an object to be inserted in the receiver’s persistent store the next time changes are saved.
>
> ```
> - (void)insertObject:(NSManagedObject *)object
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *object*
>
> A managed object.

By further looking at [the documentation for -save:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save%3a) (below) you will se that it will (attempt to) save *all* the unsaved changed, in your case all 100 inserted items.

> ## save:
>
> Attempts to commit unsaved changes to registered objects to their persistent store.
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *error*
>
> A pointer to an `NSError` object. You do not need to create an `NSError` object. The save operation aborts after the first failure if you pass `NULL`.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> `YES` if the save succeeds, otherwise `NO`.

Comment: This is also very slow because the speed increase from transactions are lost. Anyway to amend that?

Answer (score 6):

```
[[<#NSManagedObjectContext#> undoManager] beginUndoGrouping];
... do some data modifications ....
[[<#NSManagedObjectContext#> undoManager] endUndoGrouping];

[[<#NSManagedObjectContext#> undoManager] undo]; // rollback
...
```